# cloudera/hue : HUE Search Dashboard promotion from one environment to other

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, hue

We have HUE (v 3.5) in you dev environment and production environment. I'm trying to propagate the dashboard I created in dev env. to prod env. Are there any chef cookbooks or any other widely accepted strategy for such env promotions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Answer (score 0):

Until https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-1660

You could try something like:

> build/env/bin/hue  dumpdata search > search.json

then:

> build/env/bin/hue  loaddata search.json